# How to pass data from UITableViewCell to a class which inheritances NSObject

Tags: ios, swift, delegates

Im trying to implement MVVM and Im using ViewController to update the UI, and a view-model to create an object and then to store all the properties of that object locally(user-defaults), now I would like to pass the data from a UITableViewCell to that NSObject class and to store it inside the object property.

TableViewCell:

```
import UIKit

protocol AlbumsPickerCellDelegate {
    func didSelectedAlbum(_ selectedAlbum: String)
}



class AlbumsPickerTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

//    var indexPath: IndexPath!

    @IBOutlet var albumsPicker: UIPickerView!
    

    
    var pickerData = ["Album1", "Album2", "Album3"]
    var albumsPickerCellDelegate:  AlbumsPickerCellDelegate?
    
    var isPickerDown = false
    
    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        // Initialization code
        self.albumsPicker.delegate = self
        self.albumsPicker.dataSource = self
        
        
        albumsPicker.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            albumsPicker.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.topAnchor),
            albumsPicker.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.bottomAnchor),
            albumsPicker.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.leadingAnchor),
            albumsPicker.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.trailingAnchor),
//            albumsPicker.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 100),
//            albumsPicker.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 40),
            albumsPicker.heightAnchor.constraint(lessThanOrEqualToConstant: 140),
            albumsPicker.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.centerXAnchor),
            albumsPicker.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.centerYAnchor)


            
        ])
        
        
        self.preservesSuperviewLayoutMargins = false
        self.separatorInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 15, bottom: 0, right: 15)
        self.layoutMargins = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 15, bottom: 0, right: 15)
    }

    
    
//    class func cellHeight() -> CGFloat {
//        return 162.0
//    }
    
    
}

extension AlbumsPickerTableViewCell: UIPickerViewDelegate, UIPickerViewDataSource {
    func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
        return 1

    }
    
    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
        return pickerData.count
    }
    
    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
        return pickerData[row]
    }
    
    
    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
        isPickerDown = true
        
        let selectedAlbumOption = pickerData[row]
        
        if let delegate = albumsPickerCellDelegate {
            delegate.didSelectedAlbum(selectedAlbumOption)
        }
        
       

        
    }
    
    
    
    
}
```

ViewModel:

```
import Foundation
import UIKit


class FilterViewModel: NSObject, AlbumsPickerCellDelegate {
    
    var albumCell = AlbumsPickerTableViewCell()
    
    //Class vars:
    var selectedActivityByUser: String?
    var selectedPostTypesByUser: [String]?
    var selectedHashTagsByUser: [String]?
    var startDate: Date?
    var endDate: Date?
    var selectedAlbumByUser: String?
    
    //    var userFilter = FilterModel(byActivity: selectedActivityByUser, postType: selectedPostTypesByUser, hashTags: selectedHashTagsByUser, startDate: startDate, endDate: endDate, album: selectedAlbumByUser)
    
    override init() {
        super.init()
        //Sets the delegate as self:
        albumCell.albumsPickerCellDelegate = self
    }
}


//TODO: Pass all the info into FilterViewModel with delegates
extension FilterViewModel {
    
    func didSelectedAlbum(_ selectedAlbum: String) {
        self.selectedAlbumByUser = selectedAlbum
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A delegate from the **view** to the **model** is the wrong approach. It cannot work.
There are multiple table view cells and the default initializer `AlbumsPickerTableViewCell()` creates another new instance of the cell which is never used in the table view.

The correct approach is a delegate (in Swift a callback closure is preferable) from the table view cell to the view **controller** passing the data and the index path. The **controller** updates the **model** at the given index (path).

---

In `AlbumsPickerTableViewCell` add a property callback

```
weak var callback : ((UITableViewCell, String) -> Void)?
```

And replace `didSelectRow` with

```
func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
    isPickerDown = true
    
    callback?(self, pickerData[row])        
}
```

In the view controller in `cellForRow` assign the closure to `callback`, replace `datasource` with the name of the real datasource array

```
cell.callback = { actualCell, album in 
    let actualIndexPath = tableView.indexPath(for: actualCell)!
    self.datasource[actualIndexPath.row].selectedAlbumByUser = album
}
```

Delete the entire code related to the protocol/delegate.

And there is no need that the model inherits from NSObject, not even it's supposed to be a class.

Comment: I see, but what I do with the viewModel? I mean I use all that code inside the UITableViewController(cellForRow) and not in the viewModel class :)

Comment: The model is the model, it contains the data for one table view row, nothing else. On the other hand the controller manages to populate the table view and handles the user interaction. Delete `albumCell`, the `init` method and the protocol stuff.

Comment: the view-model doesnt receives information from VC, handles all this information, and sends it back to VC ? I mean I'm trying to understand how to organise all the data to that filter feature :\

Comment: There is only **one** model, I don't know what view-model means. The model-view-controller pattern is quite clear.